# cutil function compilation program

Tags: cuda

I am using some of the functions from cutil.h to time my code. It compiles fine on windows xp with vs 2008. Recently, I switch to window 7 and vs 2008. The same code doesn't compile and I have following error,

> 1>LINK : C:\Users\weiqi\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\corrColumnLateral\Debug\corrColumnLateral.exe not found
>   or not built by the last incremental link; performing full
>   link1>corrColumnLateral.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol _*imp*_cutStopTimer@4 referenced in function
>   _main1>corrColumnLateral.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_cutStartTimer@4 referenced in function
>   _main1>corrColumnLateral.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_cutResetTimer@4 referenced in function
>   _main1>corrColumnLateral.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_cutGetTimerValue@4 referenced in function
>   _main1>corrColumnLateral.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_cutCreateTimer@4 referenced in function _main

The macros from the header file, such as CUDA_SAFE_CALL, work fine, but timing functions like cutCreatTimer fail to compile. Does anyone knows what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you right click your cu source file and select properties:

Then go to CUDA C/C++ and under Common add the location of the cutil.h to the Additional Include Directories folder.

For me this was: C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 3.2\C\common\inc

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to the cutil library.  On linux it's called libcutil.so or libcutil.a.  The windows version probably also has "cutil" in its name, so you can search for that file and add it to your linker options.